# add indeterminate horizontal progress to Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to add a indeterminate horizontal progress to action bar. I try using:

```
setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

but I get a spinning wheel progress widget and not a indefinite one horisntal.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Chris Banes made a great library "ActionBar-PullToRefresh" :
https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

in which he add an other great library : SmoothProgressBar :
https://github.com/castorflex/SmoothProgressBar

The ActionBar-PullToRefresh library allow you to add a horizontal indeterminate progress bar to your ActionBar.

You can either use this library or look at is implementation to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using 
`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS)`
try using
`requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS)`

then enable with these:

```
setProgressBarIndeterminate(true);
setProgressBarVisibility(true);
```

I haven't tried it with the support class, but I guess it should work the same.