# adding a progress bar widget to action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Can I add a **progress bar** widget to **android action bar**. In my app, when **db tables** are updating can I show the **progress** in that way. Need Some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my reponse to your answer here :

[add indeterminate horizontal progress to Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18715559/add-indeterminate-horizontal-progress-to-action-bar/20606708#20606708)

ActionBar-PullToRefresh is easy to use. Check the github for more info :

https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh